# Editing attribute tables in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I have a point shapefile with several fields. Among these fields is a comment field. I would like to be able to zoom into each point and add a comment into this field in real time without having to export the attribute table, etc. Is there any way to do this in ArcMap?

Comment: Why would you need to export the attribute table to edit it? With the attribute table open (right-click layer in table of contents) and while in an edit session, you can make changes to any field/record, not just the geometry. You can even right-click a particular selected record and choose zoom-to. If you don't want the attribute table open there's always the attribute window Michael mentions, but you must select features in the map to be able to zoom to them or change attributes there.

Answer (score 1):

Well of course you can... Using the Editor toolbar!

Comment: Can you expand on this a little bit, a one-line answer does't explain very much. Have you tried the Attributes window on the editor toolbar http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m90000000m000000 ? It sounds like that would be better than editing the table directly in your situation.